# touchesmoved leave frame

Tags: iphone, objective-c, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I am trying to figure out how I can set a button to not be highlighted when touchesmoved leaves the frame of the current selected button. See code below. The below code should allow any of the three buttons to be pressed individually and swipped. The problem I am having is that when the buttons a swipped eg using touchesmoved the buttons call the Actions but never set the buttons back to not be highlighted when the swipe leaves the button frame.

Thanks in advance,

Azza

```
- (void)touchesMoved: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for(UITouch *t in touches) { 

CGPoint location = [t locationInView:t.view]; 

if((CGRectContainsPoint(Button1.frame, location))  && (!Button1.isHighlighted))
{ 
    if (!Button1.isHighlighted){ 
       [Button1 setHighlighted:YES];
       [self doAction1]; 
     }else{
       [Button1 setHighlight:NO];
     }
 }

if((CGRectContainsPoint(Button2.frame, location))  && (!Button2.isHighlighted))
{ 
    if (!Button2.isHighlighted){ 
       [Button2 setHighlighted:YES];
       [self doAction2]; 
     }else{
       [Button2 setHighlight:NO];
     }
 }

if((CGRectContainsPoint(Button3.frame, location))  && (!Button3.isHighlighted))
{ 
    if (!Button3.isHighlighted){ 
       [Button3 setHighlighted:YES];
       [self doAction3]; 
     }else{
       [Button3 setHighlight:NO];
     }
 }
 }

- (void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
for(UITouch *t in touches) { 

CGPoint location = [t locationInView:t.view]; 

if(CGRectContainsPoint(Button1.frame, location))
{ 
    if (!Button1.isHighlighted){ 
       [Button1 setHighlighted:YES];
       [self doAction1]; 
     }
 }

if(CGRectContainsPoint(Button2.frame, location)) 
{ 
    if (!Button2.isHighlighted){ 
       [Button2 setHighlighted:YES];
       [self doAction2]; 
     }
 }

if(CGRectContainsPoint(Button3.frame, location))
{ 
    if (!Button3.isHighlighted){ 
       [Button3 setHighlighted:YES];
       [self doAction3]; 
     }
 }
 }


- (void)touchesEnded: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    for (UITouch *t in touches){
    CGPoint location = [t locationInView:self.view]; 

    if(CGRectContainsPoint(Button1.frame, location)) {    
        [Button1 setHighlighted:NO];

    } else if(CGRectContainsPoint(Button2.frame, location)) { 
           [Button2 setHighlighted:NO];

    } else if(CGRectContainsPoint(Button3.frame, location)) { 
       [Button3 setHighlighted:NO];
    }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I know I've handled this same issue before. I also see a reference to it in my own comments in the code. I've attached a chunk of very old code that I wrote to handle simulated buttons (similar to what you are doing). Maybe looking through this will help:

```
typedef struct {
            BOOL enabled;
            BOOL isActivated;
            NSTimeInterval activatedStartTime;
            NSTimeInterval holdTime;
            CGRect frame;
            UIImageView *glowImage;
            BOOL processPending;
            SEL callWhenTouched;
            } SIM_BUTTON;



- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    int fingers = [touches count];
    UITouch *touch;
    CGPoint touchPoint;
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<fingers; i++)
        {
        touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
        touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];


        for ( j=0; j<SIM_BUTTON_COUNT; j++)
            {
            if ( simButton[j].enabled && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, touchPoint) )
                {
                simButton[j].isActivated=YES;
                simButton[j].activatedStartTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
                simButton[j].processPending = YES;
                }
            }
        }
    }



- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    int fingers = [touches count];
    UITouch *touch;
    CGPoint touchPoint;
    CGPoint previousTouchPoint;
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<fingers; i++)
        {
        touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
        touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        previousTouchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];

        for ( j=0; j<SIM_BUTTON_COUNT; j++)
            {
            if ( simButton[j].enabled && simButton[j].isActivated && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, touchPoint) && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, previousTouchPoint) )
                {
                simButton[j].isActivated=YES;
                }
            else
            if ( simButton[j].enabled && !simButton[j].isActivated && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, touchPoint) && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, previousTouchPoint) )
                {
                simButton[j].activatedStartTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
                simButton[j].isActivated=YES;
                }
            else
            if ( simButton[j].enabled && simButton[j].isActivated && !CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, touchPoint) && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, previousTouchPoint) )
                {
                simButton[j].isActivated=NO;
                simButton[j].activatedStartTime = (NSTimeInterval)0.0;
                }
            else
            if ( simButton[j].enabled && !simButton[j].isActivated && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, touchPoint) && !CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, previousTouchPoint) )
                {
                simButton[j].isActivated=YES;
                simButton[j].activatedStartTime = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];
                simButton[j].processPending = YES;
                }

            //
            // If the user touched the SCAN button and then slid their finger off of the SCAN button
            //
            if ( scannerActive==YES && simButton[RIGHT_SCAN_BUTTON].isActivated==NO && CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[RIGHT_SCAN_BUTTON].frame, previousTouchPoint) )
                {
                phraseMode = EXTERNAL_SCAN_PHRASES;     // Default
                }
            }
        }
    }



- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    int fingers = [touches count];
    UITouch *touch;
    CGPoint touchPoint;
    CGPoint previousTouchPoint;
    int i, j;

    for (i=0; i<fingers; i++)
        {
        touch = [[touches allObjects] objectAtIndex:i];
        touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        previousTouchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];

        for ( j=0; j<SIM_BUTTON_COUNT; j++)
            {
            if ( simButton[j].enabled && simButton[j].isActivated && (CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, touchPoint) || CGRectContainsPoint( simButton[j].frame, previousTouchPoint)) )
                {
                simButton[j].isActivated=NO;
                simButton[j].activatedStartTime = (NSTimeInterval)0.0;
                }
            }
        }
    }



- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
    {
    [self touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event];
    }
```

Comment: That got the swipping working fine sort of. But now when i swipe a button and release between both of them the first initial button stays highlighted. code ia dded is below if((!CGRectContainsPoint(Button1.frame, location)) && if(CGRectContainsPoint(Button1.frame, previouslocation))) { [button1 setHighlighted:NO];} i added one of these for each button

Comment: OK, I've updated my answer with a chunk of old code where I know i was dealing with this exact same problem. Probably writing it as an object instead of a struct would be the approach I would use now

Comment: Thanks, Ill try it out when i get home and let you know how i go